# What is the gain of a telescope?

Tags: telescope, photometry

What is the gain of a telescope? How would I go about calculating the gain from a flatfield image?

Comment: Gain=Power(output)/Power(input)
db=10log(Gain)
Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you mean the gain of the detector? i.e. Number of electrons per ADU?

Answer (score 2):

[Gain in electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gain_(electronics)) can have different meanings:

> Gain is a measure of the ability of a [...] [device] to increase the power or amplitude of a signal from the input to the output port. [...] The term gain alone is ambiguous, and can refer to the ratio of output to input voltage (voltage gain), current (current gain) or electric power (power gain).

For optics, I found the [light-gathering power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_telescope#Light-gathering_power) the most appropriate measure, which relates the [apparture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture) of the telescope with the one of the human eye:

> The light-gathering power of an optical telescope, also referred to as light grasp or aperture gain, is the ability of a telescope to collect a lot more light than the human eye. Its light-gathering power is probably its most important feature. [...]
> The gathering power $P$ compared against a human eye is the squared result of the division of the aperture $D$ over the observer's pupil diameter $D_{p}$ [...] An example gathering power of [a telescope with] [...] $254\,{\rm mm}$ [aparture] compared to an adult pupil diameter being $7 \, {\rm mm}$ is given by:
> $$P = \left(\frac {D}{D_{p}}\right)^2 = \left(\frac {254}{7}\right)^2 \approx 1316.7$$

**Edit:** After the question changed slightly, I guess I should add a bit on "how to calculate gain from an image": Gain requires always *two* measurements, e.g. the image from your telescope and a base of comparison, e.g. the human eye, that's why I found the aperature-based-gain definition appealing.

If you have a datafile with intensities from your telescope - basically an image in grayscales depicting the spatial light intensity distribution - you would have to compile an image of the same area of the sky which serves you as a base of comparison.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the gain of a telescope?

I'll answer this from a different perspective. The [gain of an antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_gain) such as a radio telescope can be defined as the ratio over the gain of an [isotropic antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_radiator#Antenna_theory). For example, a simple, bare, [half-wave dipole has a gain of 1.6 dBi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Radiation_pattern_and_gain) over isotropic.

From [this answer to *Quantitatively, why will optical communication be better than X-band for deep-space communications?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35709/12102):

### Link Budget

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24343/12102):

> $$ P_{RX} = P_{TX} + G_{TX} - L_{FS} + G_{RX} $$
>
> - $P_{RX}$: received power on Earth
> - $P_{TX}$: transmitted power by Voyager
> - $G_{TX}$: Gain of Voyagers transmitting antenna (compared to isotropic)
> - $L_{FS}$: Free space Loss, what we usually call $1/r^2$
> - $G_{RX}$: Gain of Earth's receiving antenna (compared to isotropic)
>
> $$G \sim 20 \times \log_{10}\left( \frac{\pi d}{\lambda} \right)$$
>
> $$L_{FS} = 20 \times \log_{10}\left( 4 \pi \frac{R}{\lambda} \right).$$

- [further reading](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+link+budget)

So at a wavelength of 10 centimeters, a ten meter dish will have a gain of about 70 dBi.

By extension, at a wavelength of 0.5 microns a ten centimeter amateur telescope will have a gain of 116 dBi and a 6 mm human pupil will have a gain of 91.5 dBi

That means that the telescope has a gain of 24.5 dB compared to the eye.

$10^{24.5/10}$ is (within rounding) the same as $(10/0.6)^2$.

At first you may think it strange to think of antennas for light, but this is exactly where things are going in photonics; light receivers the size of half-wave dipoles, and diodes and other circuit elements to convert light oscillations to signals that can be treated as electrical signals. This is outside the scope of Astronomy though.

Comment: Great answer, in particular that you are giving back dB values.